# What does the following error mean?

Tags: android, libgdx

I have two projects that are instantiations of actual code written in libGDX. One is the desktop version of the game, the other is the android version of the game, and the last project folder is the actual code for the game mechanics. So I have three projects in eclipse. The actual code of the game, and then two other projects that create "versions" of the game (Android and Desktop versions).

For the desktop version, the game will not run. The screen will appear, and then go away quickly. When I go to properties and linked resources, I see the following error: "Invalid Location" [image: Image of Error]

For the android version of the game, when I go to properties look under linked resources, I see nothing. Shouldn't the assets folder be linked there? [image]
Also, when I go and try to run the android version of the project, the program installs, but then the emulator says not responding. It could just be because, it's taking a long time to get the game started on the emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the library from the android tab in the properties menu?
The assets folder wont show in the linked resources, the only time i have ever seen items in linked resources is when i link a library project which is done on the android tab at the bottom see example:

[image: Android Resources Tab]

This then shows:

[image: linked resources tab]

Add your external JAR from the Java Build Path tab

[image]

Comment: @Kenny: When I click add, I don't have the option of adding any library

Comment: I've added an extra pic for reference, go to "Java Build Path" then select the "Libraries" tab, the click "Add External JARS"

Comment: I added the ones, that I though libGDX needed, and eclipse shut down because of some eternal error

Comment: oh dear! just found this link - have you tried this?
http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetup

Comment: well its a project that I cloned from a respository, so some of the references could be off. But I had to create a workspace to get back into eclipse. I'm just glad that I got eclipse back up, but now all my projects have been deleted from the project explorer. In any case, thanks for your efforts.

Comment: No worries! I often have issues with projects from repository's, I usually create a new project then copy the source and assets into the new project. Good Luck!

Comment: Btw, once I restarted my computer, my original eclipse workspace came back :)